# Where to find a barber in Fallout NV?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Is there a barber available in Fallout New Vegas? Sporting hipster beard in Mojave desert almost makes me wish for a nuclear winter.

Comment: Pretty sure you can find a barber module for the autodoc in Old World Blues; dunno about in the base game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only appears to be one way and that is using Sergio.

Sergio is a member of the Kings living in Freeside. He is located near the southernmost corner of the first floor of The King's School of Impersonation.

- The Courier can only take advantage of Sergio's services if the Courier joins the Kings, which can be done by completing the Kings quest-line and gaining the King's one favor.

Source: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sergio